# Title and author falsely printed in one line using apa7, stu mode, noextraspace

Tags: apa7

I have a problem with the [apa7 package](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/apa7) in `stu` mode. I tried using the option `noextraspace` in `\documentclass` because the spacing between headings of the same layer and the trailing text bodies varied. When I used `noextraspace` this problem was solved but another one occurred: on the title page, title and author were printed in one line. This, of course, does not work. I have no idea how to fix this problem.

I would be very glad to receive Your suggestions :-)

```
\documentclass[stu, fontsize = 10pt, a4paper,noextraspace, floatsintext]{apa7} 
% noextraspace: stu mode, removes some of the vertical space between certain elements 
% (e.g., headers and text) to more closely resemble true double-spacing (at your own risk).

\usepackage[american]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\linespread{1.5}

\usepackage[style=apa,sortcites=true,sorting=nyt,backend=biber]{biblatex}
%\DeclareLanguageMapping{american}{american-apa}
\addbibresource{trees.bib}

\title{Depression among Trees}

\author{Alpha Beta}
\affiliation{Department of Psychology}

\course{Cours XY}
\professor{Dr. Dr.}
\duedate{March 31, 2100}


\abstract{Blabla Blubbblubb}


\begin{document}
\maketitle
Blabla Blubbblubb

\end{document}
```

[image: output of MWE showing the problem]

Comment: Mhh, with `apa7.cls` v2.07 (2020/12/05 ), which isn't even the newest version, title and author are on separate lines in your MWE. Do you have a current version of `apa7.cls`? Can you share the `.log` file of your LaTeX run on the MWE with us (it might be too long for the question, so you can upload it to a text-sharing website such as https://pastebin.com/ or https://gist.github.com/)?

Comment: Completely, unrelated to your question, but for APA style I would replace `\usepackage[style=apa,sortcites=true,sorting=nyt,backend=biber]{biblatex}` with `\usepackage[style=apa, backend=biber]{biblatex}`: `sortcites` is already implied by `style=apa,` and `sorting=nyt,` actually disables APA sorting. The commented line`%\DeclareLanguageMapping{american}{american-apa}` can be removed with versions of `biblatex-apa` released after November 2018.

Comment: Thank you, moewe, for your comment. The second one I applied directly. It works but didn't influence the output until now. For the first one, I need to do some research on which is my current version of apa7.cls (and where I can even find it or change it).

Comment: Add `\listfiles` to the top of your `.tex` file (even before `\documentclass`). Then compile your document. You will find all package versions neatly listed in the `.log` file. But if you just upload the whole `.log` file as suggested in my first post, we can have a look at the package versions as well.

Comment: Dear moewe, you were right with the idea that an older version of apa7.cls caused the issue. It was a small operation on my software distribution to include a new file but now it works:-)) Thank you!

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the issue was due to a bug in the class, that has been promptly fixed.

Answer (score 0):

This bug was corrected in apa7 version 2.05. The latest version is 2.10 and can be found on [CTAN](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/apa7).